# why showing error like--the method getid() is undefined for the type student?

Tags: java, spring, compiler-errors

**My class Student** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPdcu.png))

```
package Model;
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String college;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getCollege() {
        return college;
    }
    public void setCollege(String college) {
        this.college = college;
    }

}
```

**my DaoClass**

```
package Dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

import Model.Student;

public class DaoClass1  implements DaoInterface{
    int id;
    String college,name,location;
    private DataSource ds;  

    public DataSource getDs() {
        return ds;
    }

    public void setDs(DataSource ds) {
        this.ds = ds;
    }

    @Override
    public int save() throws SQLException {
      Connection conn=this.getDs().getConnection();
      Statement st=conn.createStatement();
      Student stu=new Student();
      id=stu.getId();
      name=stu.getName();
      location=stu.getLocation();
      college=stu.getCollege();



      String query="INSERT INTO `myfirsttable`(``, `name`, `location`, `college`) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+location+"','"+college+"')";
      int i= st.executeUpdate(query);
      return 1;

    }

}
```

**showing compile time error as the method getId is undefined for the type Student..**  *I am practicing spring framework ... so plz help me how to overcome this compile time error...*

Comment: You code looks ok. Can you add a screenshot of the compile time error?

Comment: as a sidenote, use a `PreparedStatment` to create the query. As of now it would be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Another side note: the result of `new Student()` is probably going to be an empty student, with null name, zero id, etc., so there is really no point in saving that in the database. You probably want to put some data in the `Student` object. Also, package names should not start with a capital letter (`Model` is a bad name). Are you sure you compiled the `Student` class before trying to compile the DAO?

Comment: i am making form from spring framework so dont worry about empty student... i will provide those by controller class

Comment: @Jens i update my code with a screenshot

Comment: @HemantDhanuka Your Student class is not saved. Maybe that is the problem

Comment: Are you sure you have good import? Maybe ther's another Student class in your project or in dependencies

Comment: @jens problem solved... Student Class was not saved.. thankew bro